# Find all values for $x$ for which the following is true $(x-y)(x+y) = px$, where $p$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$(x-y)(x+y) = px$ where $x$ is a nonzero integer and $y,p$ are positive integers

So far I have looked at $2$ cases:

1. If $x$, and $y$ are both divisible by $p$.
2. If only one is divisible by $p$.

But I am not sure how to solve the case if none of $x$ or $y$ is divisible by $p$. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(x-y)(x%2By)%3Dpx%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime&p=1), I found the AoPS thread [Perfect square](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1389699p7743684), in particular it's [post #$4$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1389699p11562538).

Comment: @JohnOmielan Unfortunately, that thread is using the equivalent of $y^2 = x^2 +px$, but this problem has $y^2=x^2\mathbf{-}px$

Comment: Eric, just change the sign of x.

Comment: @gnasher729 OK, sure, but then you have to change the sign back when you get the solution.

Comment: Use the fact that, since $p$ is prime, if $p$ divides $AB$, then $p$ divides $A$ or $p$ divides $B$ and work on both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange the original equation as $y^2 = x^2-xp = x(x-p)$. There is some value (or values) $n = y^2 = x(x-p)$ that has two different factorizations and is still a perfect square. This implies that $n = a^2b^2$ for some integers $a, b$.

Consider the possibility that the factorization is as simple as possible, that is (for only positive integers for the moment): $y=ab, \ x=a^2, \ x-p =b^2$. This also implies $p=a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$. Primes tend to resist factorization like that, unless one of the factors is $1$. But we know that all odd primes, and indeed all odd numbers, are the differences of *consecutive* squares. Hence:

$$a-b=1, a+b=p \implies a=b+1, \color{blue}{p=2b+1, x=(b+1)^2, y=b(b+1)}$$

where $b= \frac{p-1}{2}$. To get rid of $a$ and $b$ completely, we have:

$$\color{red}{x_1 = \left(\frac{p+1}{2}\right)^2, y_1= \left( \frac{p+1}{2} \right)\left( \frac{p-1}{2} \right)}$$

This curve is symmetric across the $x$ axis, but we're asked specifically for positive values of $y$. But what about possible negative values of $x$? After all, we have a hyperbola here. The original equation would become $y^2 = x^2 +px$, leading eventually to $p=b^2-a^2$, and to the following:

$$\color{red}{x_2 = -\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)^2, y_2= \left( \frac{p+1}{2} \right)\left( \frac{p-1}{2} \right)}$$

These are the two solutions, ignoring the reflection into negative $y$ territory.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2-y^2=px\iff x^2-px-y^2=0\Rightarrow 2x=p\pm\sqrt{p^2+(2y)^2}=p\pm z$ where $z=r^2+s^2$ and$p=r^2-s^2$ and $2y=2rs$ (by Phytagorean triples). It follows because $p$ must be prime that $r-s=1$ and $p=r+s=2s+1$. From this we have
$$2x=\frac{2s+1\pm(2s^2+2s+1)}{2}\iff x=\begin{cases}s^2+2s+1=(s+1)^2\\s^2\end{cases}$$ in both cases we can verify that $x^2-y^2=px$. In fact we have
$$(1)\space x^2-y^2=(s+1)^4-s^2(s+1)^2=p(s+1)^2\iff (s+1)^2-s^2=2s+1=p\\\space (2) x^2-y^2=s^4-s^2(s+1)^2=ps^2\iff(s+1)^2-s^2=2s+1=p$$.

Thus, **if the prime $p=2s+1$ then the required $x$ can have the two values,$s^2$ and $(s+1)^2$**.

What if $p=2$ ? I leave the answer to the O.P.

Comment: $x =s^2$ definitely does not give a valid solution in the integers. Foe $p=2, 3$ it gives no valid solution at all.

Comment: Did you mean instead $-s^2$ ?

Comment: It is obviously a lapse.

Comment: You can't deny the identities with the values $x=(s+1)^2, y=s(s+1)$ $$ (s+1)^4-s^2(s+1)^2=p(s+1)^2\iff (s+1)^2-s^2=p$$ when $p$ is an odd prime equal to $2s+1$. With the value $x=-s^2$ we have $$ (-s^2)^2-s^2(s+1)^2=p(-s^2)\iff -s^2+(s+1)^2=p$$

Answer (score -1):

x^2-y^2 = px. If x=0 then y^2=0, y=0, p may be any prime. If y=0 then x^2 = px then x=p; the case x=0 was already covered.

Divide by x. x-y^2/x = p. Define z by factoring x into primes, and replacing any exponent e with e/2, rounded up to an integer. Then t = z^2 / x is the product of all prime factors of x with odd exponent, and y^2 / x equals t multiplied by any square.

Example: x = 8 * 9 * 5, z = 4 * 3 * 5, t = z^2/x = 2 * 5. We see x - y^2*z is divisible by 10, therefore not prime.

x cannot have two or more prime factors raised to an odd exponent. x can have exactly one one prime factor raised to an odd exponent, x = q n^2 for some prime q, z = qn, t = z^2/x = q. We have x-y^2/x = q n^2 - k^2q = p. This implies q=p, n^2-k^2 =1. n=+/-1, k=0, so y=0 which we handled.

x may have no prime factor raised to an odd power. x = +/- n^2. This makes t = 1, so y^2 can be any square. n^2 - y^2 = p. The difference between squares isn’t 2, but it can be any odd number, including any prime other than 2. One of n and y is odd, one is even; the difference is odd. But the difference of two squares is (n+y)(n-y), there are two factors unless n-y = 1, so n= y+1. 2y+1 must be prime.

So p is any odd prime, y = +/- ((p-1)/2), x = ((p+1)/2). That’s it.

Comment: This solution is incorrect. As a fast example, if $p=3, y=\pm 1, x=2$ is not a solution, as it would give $(2-1)(2+1)=3\cdot 2 \implies 3 = 6$, obviously false.